# Are $\pi$ and $e$ algebraically independent?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

Update Edit : Title of this question formerly was "Is there a polynomial relation between $e$ and $\pi$?"

Is there a polynomial relation (with algebraic numbers as coefficients) between $e$ or $\pi$ ?
For example does there exists algebraic numbers $a_1,a_2,..,a_n$ s.t. 
$$a_n e^n + a_{n-1}e^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0e^0 = \pi$$ or 
$$a_n \pi^n + a_{n-1}\pi^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0\pi^0 = e$$

Comment: I believe the answer to this is not known.

Comment: I'm looking up things, I don't see anything decisive, but it's fair to say that the collection of similar problems that can be resolved is vanishingly small.

Comment: It's not known for coefficients from $\Bbb{Q}$: isn't this equivalent to coefficients from $\bar{\Bbb{Q}}$?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, this is indeed an open problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence#Algebraic_independence_of_known_constants

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, [this is an open problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence#Algebraic_independence_of_known_constants) (as of $17$ years ago, anyway). A common phrase to describe the question (which will help with searches) is "are $\pi$ and $e$ *algebraically independent*".

an important related problem is the validity of [Schanuel's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture).

[A related thread from over at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33817/work-on-independence-of-pi-and-e/33820#33820)

Comment: Feel free to update this answer with more useful/reliable sources.