# Is $\large \frac {\pi}{e}$ rational, irrational, or trandescendal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, pi, transcendental-numbers

Is there an argument for why $\large \frac {\pi}{e}$ is rational, irrational, or trandescendal? Can the quotient of any two transcendental numbers (which are not rational multiples of each other) be rational, or at least irrational? Thanks.

Comment: If the quotient of any two transcendental numbers, they are rational multiples of each other.

Comment: Also, the quotient of two transcendental numbers is either going to be rational or irrational, so I don't understand what your second question is supposed to be about (I assume you're just wondering when (if at all possible) the quotient of two transcendental numbers is rational).

Comment: @AndrewD Sorry about that, I fixed the question now. I mean to say that if the quotient is not transcendental, can it at least be irrational.

Comment: @AndrewD The quotient of two transcendentals can be transcendental, e.g. $\frac{\sin 1}{\cos 1}$.

Comment: ... and the quotient of some other two transcendentals can be rational, e.g. $(2\pi)/\pi$.  And the quotent of some other two transcendentals can be irrational and algebraic, e.g. $(\pi\sqrt{2})/\pi$.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456097/are-pi-and-e-algebraically-independent

Comment: The quotient of two transcendentals can be anything except $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $e$ also $\frac{1}{e}$ is transcendental. The polynomial $(x-\pi)(x-\frac{1}{e})=x^2-(\frac{1}{e}+\pi)+\frac{\pi}{e}$ cannot have rational coefficients, hence either $\frac{1}{e}+\pi$ or $\frac{\pi}{e}$ is irrational. 
But indeed, the question is whether $π$ and $e$ are algebraically independent. See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33817/work-on-independence-of-pi-and-e.