# Are there integers $a, b$ such that $\pi^a = e^b$?

Tags: irrational-numbers, transcendental-equations

Is $\log \pi $ a rational number? That is, are there non-zero integers $a, b$ s.th. $\pi^a = e^b$ ?

Comment: I don't believe it is known. The algebraic independence of $\pi$ and $e$ is still an open problem.

Comment: Of course you can always take a=b=0.

Comment: @nik: doesn't this count as a dependency: $e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0$?

Comment: @barakmanos Doesn't algebraic independence require algebraic expressions, e.g. $\mathbb{Q}[\mathrm{e},\pi]$. I don't think that one thing to the power of the other is allowed.

Comment: @awllower: Thank you, I just specified the problem a bit more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are $\pi$ and $e$ algebraically independent?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456097/are-pi-and-e-algebraically-independent)

Comment: Well, if it was known that $\log \pi$ is rational, it would probably be known to virtually everyone. No way it would escape universal attention. So my guess is either "no" or "it's unknown".

Comment: @FlybyNight I think $x^a-y^b$ is a polynomial in two variables?

Comment: I fail to see how not knowing whether $e$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent entails not knowing whether $\log \pi$ is rational. If the logarithm is irrational (which is reasonable to assume), then it doesn't tell us much about algebraic independence. Or does it?

Comment: Even if we knew that $\log \pi$ were irrational, it wouldn't prove that $\pi$ and $e$ were algebraically independent (though the converse does hold).  This isn't a strict duplicate.  That said, I doubt that $\log\pi$ has been proven to be irrational.

Comment: @T.Bongers: It's not a duplicate. If $\pi$ and $e$ are algebraically independent, then $\log(\pi)$ is irrational. The converse isn't true.

Comment: @awllower You're absolutely right that $x^a-y^b$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$ when $a$ and $b$ are non-negative integers. However, the example of $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi} + 1$ is as much of a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[\pi,\mathrm{e}]$ as $x^y$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$. In one dimension: $x^2+1$ is a polynomial but $2^x+1$ and $x^x+1$ are not.

Comment: @FlybyNight Sorry, I thought you were referring to nik. Apology here.

Comment: Maybe using $\log_\pi(x)$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still an open problem. The algebraic independence of $\pi$ and $e$ is unknown, i.e., it is unknown whether there exist algebraic numbers $n_0, n_1, \ldots, n_k$ such that

$$
n_{0} \pi^{0} + \ldots + n_{k-1} \pi^{k-1} + n_k \pi^{k} = e.
$$

Comment: This fails to answer the question; even if they are algebraically dependent, it will not imply that the answer to the question is "yes". Furthermore, for all we know it may be possible to prove that the answer is "no" **without** being able to establish algebraic independence.