# Is $\log 2\pi$ rational?

Tags: logarithms, irrational-numbers, pi, transcendental-numbers, rationality-testing

Is it known whether $\log 2\pi$ is rational (where the base of the logarithm is $e$)? Or algebraic?

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Mike can you expand on this?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456097/are-pi-and-e-algebraically-independent/456131#456131)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to see if $(2\pi)^q=e^p$ for some $p,q\in\Bbb Z$, in particular this means $e,\pi$ are not algebraically independent (over $\Bbb Q$). This is not known to the date.

Comment: Although I'd be willing to place a rather large wager that they *are* independent.

Comment: Thanks. So if the answer is that $\log 2\pi$ is rational, then it would imply a currently unknown result. However if $\log 2\pi$ is irrational, then this negative answer would not be strong enough to resolve the algebraic independence or non-independence of $\pi$ and $e$ (i.e., even though $(2\pi)^q = e^p$ would be impossible, there still might be a polynomial relationship between $\pi$ and $e$ of another form). Is the negative answer also unproven?

Comment: To my knowledge, it's unproven. So is the question of rationality of even more basic expressions such as $\pi + e$ or $\pi e$.

Comment: @user7530 there is a proof that $\pi + e$ and $\pi e $ cannot both be rational.