# Is there such a thing as "quadratic independence" (and higher generalizations of linear independence)?

Tags: linear-algebra

The notion of [*linear independence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) is very well-known and well-understood.

However, is there a way to generalize the definition to other types of independence -- such as perhaps "quadratic independence", "polynomial independence", "harmonic independence", etc.?

(Sorry if [linear-algebra](/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) isn't a good tag; I couldn't think of a better one.)

Comment: Linear independence comes from linear combination. How would one generalize this to quadratic combinations ??

Comment: @daw I think that's the essence of the question

Comment: Aside from algebraic independence, the other thing that comes to mind is the concept of "matroid", which is the sort of abstract general structure linear independent sets of vectors have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a result of my search for answers to this question, here is the answer I encountered:

For a set $\{x^1,\ldots x^k\}\subseteq F^s$ the set is quadratically dependent if there are coefficients $a_1,\ldots ,a_k$ not all zero such that:
$$\forall i_1,i_2\in[s]:\ \sum_{j=1}^{k}a_j(x^j_{i_1})(x^j_{i_2})=0$$

Similarly, one can define $n$-degree dependence by considering monomials of degree n, instead of 2.

My answer is based on [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2098698) paper by H. Tatcher Jr.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm a little bit confused by the notation though. If you fix $i_1$ and $i_2$ then what is $j$ doing there? The elements of the set are just `x[1] ... x[k]`, right? Why are there 2 subscripts (/superscripts) instead of just 1?

Comment: This is a definition of quadratic dependence for a set of $k$ vectors in $F^s$, that’s what the j’s stand for. $i_1,i_2$ are the coordinates (between $1\to s$). 

For example, if $s=3$, and $k=4$, with $x_1=(1,0,0),x_2=(0,1,0),x_3=(1,1,0),x_4=(0,0,0)$, we have the following 6 equations (corresponding to choosing 2 elements of a 3 element set with replacement):

Comment: $a_1(1)^2+a_2(0)^2+a_3(1)^2+a_4(0)^2=0$,  $a_1(1)(0)+a_2(0)(1)+a_3(1)(1)+a_4(0)(0)=0$,         $a_1(1)(0)+a_2(0)(0)+a_3(1)(0)+a_4(0)(0)=0$,  
      $a_1(0)^2+a_2(1)^2+a_3(1)^2+a_4(0)^2=0$,        $a_1(0)(0)+a_2(1)(0)+a_3(1)(0)+a_4(0)(0)=0$,        $a_1(0)^2+a_2(0)^2+a_3(0)^2+a_4(0)^2=0$

Comment: Given by the monomials: $x_1^2,x_1x_2,x_1x_3,x_2^2,x_2x_3,x_3^2$

Comment: If there are $a_1,\ldots, a_4$ such that these equations are all satisfied, then the elements may be called quadratically dependent, and otherwise, quadratically independent.

Comment: +1 Interesting, thanks. But does this mean the linear version of this is actually different than our definition of linear independence in linear algebra? Since in this case we're defining an inner product over nth-degree products, whereas linear dependence just looks at 1st-degree products (i.e. the vectors themselves) and linearly combines those without involving an inner product.

Comment: Actually, in the linear version you get precisely the same definition as your usual linear dependence. Indeed, in our running example, these are the equations corresponding to $x_1,x_2,x_3$, so we get the equations: $b_1(1)+b_2(0)+b_3(1)+b_4(0)=0$, $b_1(0)+b_2(1)+b_3(1)+b_4(0)=0$, $b_1(0)+b_2(0)+b_3(0)+b_4(0)=0$, which is solved with the same coefficients as the vector equation $b_1(1,0,0)+b_2(0,1,0)+b_3(1,1,0)+b_4(0,0,0)=(0,0,0)$.

Comment: We do not define an inner product here - we solve the equations $\sum_{x\in\{x^1,\ldots , x^k\}}a_x\cdot x_i x_j$ for every two coordinates $i$ and $j$, where $a_x$ is uniform over choices of a pair of coordinates (but not necessarily over the different choices for $x$).

Comment: Ohh I see! I misunderstood what was going on. Very nice, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

There is "algebraic independence" - if there is a non-zero polynomial $f$ of $n$ variables, with coefficients in the field $K$, such that
$$f(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)=0\ ,$$
then $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ are said to be algebraically dependent over $K$; if there is no such polynomial then they are algebraically independent over $K$.

For example, $\pi$ and $\sqrt{2\pi}$ are algebraically dependent over $\Bbb Q$ because if $f(z_1,z_2)=2z_1-z_2^2$ then $f(\pi,\sqrt{2\pi})=0$.

It would seem totally plausible that $e$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent, but as far as I know this is still an unsolved problem - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456097).

For a small number of examples and general theorems on algebraically independent numbers look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence).

There is also a general concept of dependence relations which includes linear dependence and algebraic dependence as special cases.  Haven't searched online but you can find it in N. Jacobson, *Basic Algebra* vol.II, section 3.6.

Comment: +1 fantastic answer. I'll keep the question open for a bit to see if there are other ones coming, but will probably accept this haha.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that $x$ and $y$ are *quadratically dependent* if there exist constants $a,$ $b,$ $\ldots,$ $f$ not all equal to $0$ such that
$$ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dx + ey + f = 0$$

Here, $x$ and $y$ can be real numbers (or complex numbers), or real-valued functions (or complex-valued functions), or other contexts where this makes sense.

I've actually used this idea in classes (I used the phrase *quadratically related*) as an intuitive explanation of why compositions like $\sin(\arccos x)$ wind up being relatively simple functions in the sense that only squares and square roots are involved, and no transcendental functions. The explanation is that each trig function is quadratically related to every other trig function, so while the sine function doesn't entirely un-do the arc-cosine function, it comes "quadratically close" to doing so because the sine and cosine functions are quadratically related.

Comment: Isn't there *always* an $f$ that makes this true in the case of numbers?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Ah, good catch! Should be rational coefficients for numbers. And for functions it seems that two potentially useful classifications arise: using real numbers as coefficients or using rational functions (with real number coefficients) as coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, the question is:

> Is "linear independence" a special case of a more general notion of
>   independence?

Yes, it is.

> **Definition.** Let $\mathbf{C}$ denote a concrete category whose forgetful functor $U_\mathbf{C} : \mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ has a left-adjoint $F_\mathbf{C} : \mathbf{Set} \rightarrow \mathbf{C}$. Consider an object $X$ and function $f : I \rightarrow U_\mathbf{C}(X)$ from some index set $I$. Then $f$ is *independent/generating/basislike* iff the corresponding morphism $F_\mathbf{C}(I) \rightarrow X$ is injective/surjective/bijective.

Examples:

- If $\mathbf{C}$ is the category of $R$-modules for some commutative ring $R$, then $F_\mathbf{C}(I)$ equals $R^I_{\mathrm{fin}}$ and these terms mean what they usually mean. For example, $f : I \rightarrow U_\mathbf{C}(X)$ is independent in the above sense iff it is linearly independent in the usual sense iff the corresponding linear transform $R^I_{\mathrm{fin}} \rightarrow X$ is injective.
- Consider a field extension $E/F$. Functions into $E$ from some index set are algebraically independent over $F$ in the usual sense iff they're the independent in the above sense when $E$ is viewed as a commutative $F$-algebra.
- No non-empty subset of a finite group is ever independent, since all non-trivial free groups are infinite.

Comment: Man this answer is so confusing. I really was a terrible writer four years ago...