# Can a fraction of irrational numbers be an integer (specific case)?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integers, irrational-numbers

Can the fraction $\frac{\pi b}{a - e b}$ where $e$ is the usual Euler constant, and $a$,$b$ are integers, be equal to an non-zero integer ?

Comment: Almost surely not, but no one knows. This is essentially the same question:  [Are $\pi$ and $e$ algebraically independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456097/are-pi-and-e-algebraically-independent)

Comment: Equivalent question:  are $1,\pi,e$ linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$?  This is **much weaker** than whether $\pi,e$ are algebraically independent.

Comment: Can we go 'anywhere', for example by suggesting the fraction $\frac{\pi b}{a - e b} = 2$?

Comment: You might be interested to know that e.g. $\frac{\log 2}{1-\log 5}=1$, which is indeed the fraction of two irrational numbers.

Comment: @Trebor Also: $\frac {10\pi}{5\pi}, \frac {6e}{2e}, \dots$

Answer (score 3):

I want to show that the following *elementary* conclusion :

> Let $\thinspace (a,b)\in\mathbb Z^{2}\setminus \{0\}\thinspace $, then $\thinspace\frac{\pi b}{a-eb}\thinspace$ *might be* equal to some integer, only if when $\thinspace\frac {e}{\pi}\thinspace$ is irrational .

Let $\thinspace m\in\mathbb Z\thinspace $ and $\thinspace\frac ab =r\in\mathbb Q\thinspace$ with $\thinspace ab≠0\thinspace $, then we have :

$$
\begin{align}\frac{\pi b}{a-e b}&=\frac{\pi}{r-e }=m
\end{align}
$$

This leads to :

$$
\begin{align}&r=e+\frac {\pi}{m}\\
\implies &\frac {r}{\pi}=\frac {e}{\pi}+\frac 1m
\end{align}
$$

Since $\thinspace \frac{r}{\pi}\thinspace$ is irrational and $\thinspace\frac 1m\thinspace$ is rational, this implies that $\thinspace\frac {e}{\pi}\thinspace$ is irrational, but this is an [open problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number#Open_questions.) , in mathematics .

---

Then, I want to show that another *elementary* conclusion :

> If there exists non-zero integer pair $\thinspace(a,b)\thinspace$ such that, $\thinspace m=\frac{\pi b}{a-eb}\thinspace$ is an integer, then there exists at most one integer $\thinspace m\thinspace .$

Indeed, we have :

$$
\begin{align}&\begin{cases}\frac {r_1}{\pi}=\frac {e}{\pi}+\frac {1}{m_1} \\
\frac {r_2}{\pi}=\frac {e}{\pi}+\frac {1}{m_2}\end{cases}\\\\
\implies &\frac {r_1-r_2}{\pi}=\frac {m_2-m_1}{m_1m_2}\end{align}
$$

Finally, we observe that if $\thinspace r_1≠r_2\thinspace $, then $\thinspace \frac {m_2-m_1}{m_1m_2}\not\in\mathbb Q\thinspace .$

A contradiction .

Comment: Are you saying if there is an integer equal to that fraction, then $\frac{e}{\pi}$ is indeed irrational ?

Comment: @Abel Yes. Exactly .